# How to share Java Enums with Swagger CodeGen

Tags: java, enums, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have this definition on my .yaml:

```
Entity:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      name:
        type: string
      active:
        type: string
        enum: [Y, N]
```

That generate this enum on my Entity Class (Java):

```
public enum ActiveEnum {
    Y("Y"),    
    N("N");

    //...
}
```

But I want to reference another generic enum like YesOrNoEnum. To share with all APIs that have a enum with the values 'Y' and 'N' instead of creating the same enum for everyone.

There is a way to do that?